# Feature Request: Information about last update before a Suggested Edit

Tags: feature-request, review-system, suggested-edits

When I'm reviewing suggested edits, part of the overall context is whether or not the question is on or near the front page. If someone wants to add mathjax, or fix a silly typo, or add commas, I'm all in favor of this as long as it's not bumping a long-dormant question. If it is bumping an inactive thread, I might be more likely to reject the edit as not adding value.

> Would others support requesting a modification of the software so that reviewers could see when the last activity on a question occurred, prior to the suggested edit?

Currently, the only way I know to get this info is to click on the question title and then scroll through the question and answer to see what's most recent. Thanks.

Comment: The problems you describe in your post are the reason why I sometimes explicitly point out in edit summary that the question has been bumped already before my edit - to make life for the reviewers a bit easier, like [here](http://mathoverflow.net/review/suggested-edits/69051).

Comment: I do the same when I make edits. But often when reviewing edits, the only info I have is when the post was originally made.

Comment: You can open the question in a separate tab to see. This is what I usually do. I can also see better how the question looks now.